# R using mclust for gaussian mixture mode how to get number of iterations

Tags: r, iteration, cluster-analysis

I am running clustering using the mclust function. In need to get the number of iterations the algorithm used to get the answer. I can't seem to find it anywhere. I do not mind using other function that will perform "gaussian mixture mode" using EM if it will provide me the number of iteration as part of it's output.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no clear way to extract this, as far as I can tell. Here's a pretty hacky and approximate way to get at it though.

You can set the maximum number of iterations for EM using the `control` parameter,

```
x<-c(rnorm(100),rnorm(100,10,1))
mod<-Mclust(x,control = emControl(itmax=100))
```

These are set to `Inf` by default and so the EM will terminate only when the log likelihood changes in increments smaller than the tolerance. If you set `itmax`, the EM will terminate, but will throw a warning that the algorithm stopped before reaching the tolerance bounds.

So you could adjust `itmax` a few times to get a sense of how many iterations are required before the EM is naturally terminating. For example,

```
mod<-Mclust(x,control = emControl(itmax=102))
```

throws a warning but

```
mod<-Mclust(x,control = emControl(itmax=103))
```

does not.

So it seems that 103 iterations are required to reach the exit conditions (with the default tolerance parameters).

Comment: Thank you keegan. I thought of that, but from what I understand the itmax is limiting the number of iterations on all the Model Names. That means that maybe for some model it will be the limiter and for some not. I will still be unable to understand how many iterations were performed overall. Please correct me if I am wrong.